# Apache 2.4 + mod_lua: share state between requests

Tags: apache, mod-lua

Imagine you want to write your own rate limiter for Apache 2.4 based on [mod_lua](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_lua.html). The idea would be to limit the requests per time interval per IP.

For this task you need to maintain a globally accessible data structure which contains for example the count of the previous requests per IP.

mod_lua kind of supports shared memory between requests with the *ivm_set* and *ivm_get* methods but only inside one worker process:

> Values ... are stored on a per process basis (so they won't do much good with a prefork mpm)

Usually you are using more than one worker process. In our case we use mod_mpm_event with a couple of processes. How would you share this little "previous requests" data structure in that case?

The only way I can currently think of is to use a database which is supported by mod_lua. However, it seems to be a quite complex solution for such an easy task.

**Question**: How to accomplish a shared memory between all requests in mod_lua?

PS: I know there are existing rate limiters like [mod_qos](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/). Our actual use case is a different one but the rate limiter example helps to get a common understanding.